# Target Display Mode from a 2016 MacBook to a 2011 27" iMac

Tags: target-display

My Google-fu has failed me. Is it at all possible to use Target Display Mode to connect a 12-inch MacBook (early 2016) to a 27-inch iMac (Mid 2011)?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to use Target Display Mode to connect a MacBook (Early 2016) to a 27" iMac (2011)

For the Mid-2011 through Mid-2014 iMacs, you need a *Thunderbolt* cable and Thunderbolt isn't available on the Early 2016 MacBooks

[From the Thunderbolt Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)

> A Mac notebook or desktop with a Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt port.
>   [image]

From the Mac[Book (Early 2016) Tech Specs Page](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP741?locale=en_US):

- USB-C port with support for:

  - Charging
  - USB 3.1 Gen 1 (up to 5 Gbps)
  - Native DisplayPort 1.2 video output
  - VGA output using USB-C VGA Multiport Adapter (sold separately)
  - HDMI video output using USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter (sold separately)

Thunderbolt is not supported on this USB-C port.